# Using Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location to detect if file exists

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am trying to detect if a given file exists. For example, let's say I'm looking for Joystick.png in this directory: F:\FrontEnd\Themes\Custom\Images\Platform\Controller\Joystick.png

I cannot hard code the directory structure because the application might be installed elsewhere. the directory structure however, doesn't change.

I had been using this

```
string path = $"pack://siteoforigin:,,,/Themes/Custom/Images/Controls/{game.Platform}/{controller}.png";
```

to send the path to an image on the wpf but I've come to leanr that I cannot pass this same variable into `File.Exists`. So I had to come up with an alternative.

I've  discovered this:

```
string exists = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location;
```

which gets me this result: F:\FrontEnd\FrontEnd.exe

So my question is, how do I modify the `var exists` so that is matches the structure of `var path`?

Comment: `Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location` gives you everything before `/Themes/...` from the pack format.

Comment: I know that, I even posted the result. I want to replace FrontEnd.exe with the rest of my file path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the different members of `System.IO.Path` to manipulate the path strings.

```
var exePath = @"F:\FrontEnd\FrontEnd.exe";
var filePath = @"/Themes/Custom/Images/Controls/{game.Platform}/{controller}.png";
var relPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(exePath),filePath);
var packPath = @"pack://siteoforigin:,,," + relPath;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  var path = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);

  var pathtoCombine = Path.Combine(path, "themes\\custom\\images\\controls\\pc");

  var image = Path.Combine(pathtoCombine, "image.txt");
  var exists = File.Exists(image);
```

You can change `"themes\\custom\\images\\controls\\pc"` to `$"themes\\custom\\images\\controls\\{platform}\\{imagename}"`

This gives the root of your assembly. for example

> c:\users\\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\StringSandbox\StringSandbox\bin\Debug

Comment: but I don't want the root of the assembly. I want to match the file path of the path variable.

Comment: Mark your png as content and select `Copy to output directory` --> Copy always

Comment: but the image itself might not exist. The name of the image file is based on a value in a database that the user can modify. Hence, the image may or may not exist yet and if it doesn't exist, I don't want the program to crash. That's why I need to detect if the file path is valid before executing any code. Adding the image to my dll defeats entire point